# Mongodb how to connect and import data

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, homebrew

I installed mongodb in Mac by homebrew. Then I tried to start it by mongodb. Failed. Then I start it by `mongod --dbpath /data/db`. Then it is waiting forever. How to start mongodb?

```
 2015-08-22T16:08:52.619+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin mimac 14.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49 

 2015-08-22T16:08:52.619+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system

 2015-08-22T16:08:52.619+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/data/db/" } }

2015-08-22T16:08:52.628+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Answer (score 1):

To start `mongodb` automatically you can use command:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist;
```

Comment: After doing as you said. mongod is running. As if I issue mongod I get error as :  I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating. Now question is how do I import data by using mongoimport? I tried this command mongoimport --host localhost --db test --collection bank_data --type json --file bank_data.json. Then get error as Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers. I think there is be default test database exist.

Comment: Check that your user has permissions to write log files to `/var/log/mongodb/` directory (run: `mkdir /var/log/mongodb/; chown -R <YOUR_CURRENT_USER_NAME>:staff /var/log/mongodb`). Then kill all mongod processes: `sudo killall mongod` and restart `mongodb` using: `launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist; launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist;`

Answer (score 1):

1. **mongod** is the daemon (i.e the mongoDB server itself). you should run it, as you did.
2. after there is a running server, you can:

   - run the mongo shell, with the **mongo** command. this would give you an interface to the databases you have, such as querying and inserting data.
   - to import an external file into mongo database, you should use the **mongoimport** command line tool, which is provided with mongodb.

   mongoimport -d database_name -c collection_name < filename.json

mongoimport can import json, csv and tsv files.